# Send mails with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am doing on my website a reset of password, and i would like to send an email to the user who is asking this reset. I looked few packages like nodemailer and sendmail.  The problem with nodemailer, i don't want to give my email in the code, even if i'm the only who is seeing this. The problem with sendmail is:

```
error on connectMx Error: can not connect to any SMTP server
```

code sendmail :

```
const sendmail = require('sendmail')();

sendmail({
   from: 'test@test.com',
   to: 'adz@gmail.com',
   subject: 'Hello',
   html: 'test mail '
   }, function (err, reply) {
   console.log(err && err.stack)
   console.dir(reply)
}),
```

When i was working only php, there was a function called "mail", it didn't need an account gmail, hotmail ... So i'm asking to you, is there a way to don't give my account to nodemailer or not please, or is there an other way to send mails with nodeJS ?

Thanks a lot and i hope i have been clear about my problem (sorry for the bad english).

Comment: Please provide more code such as the function to send mail

Comment: That's it, I edited.